# Go colly does not perform all async calls

Tags: go, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape multiple items by asynchronously performing various 'visit' operations.
Subsequently, the result will be saved to a JSON file.
However, I noticed that some elements were missing, so I enabled the debugger.
At that point, I noticed many error logs, so I wonder what I should do to prevent HTTP requests from failing?
Here a log

```golang
[002590] 1 [   543 - error] map["status":"" "url":"https://www.example-url.com/p/xxx01/index.html"] (20.713488845s)
```

And here a code snippet with some fake urls and comments

```golang
import (
    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/gocolly/colly/v2"
    "github.com/gocolly/colly/v2/debug"
)

func main() {
    aggregator := []string{}
    baseURL := "https://www.my-category-test-list.com/index.html"

    collector := colly.NewCollector(
        colly.Async(true),
        colly.Debugger(&debug.LogDebugger{}),
    )

    collector.Limit(&colly.LimitRule{
        Parallelism: 4,
        RandomDelay: 2 * time.Second,
    })

    // This query should return 1 or more ul elements and then visiting the first page of all categories in order to look for page paginator info
    collector.OnHTML(".query-to-a-list-of-category-names ul", func(ev *colly.HTMLElement) {
        ev.DOM.Find("a").Each(func(_ int, e *goquery.Selection) {
                        // Just building the urls go to the pages with the list of items
            h, _ := e.Attr("href")
            url := ev.Request.URL.Scheme + "://" + ev.Request.URL.Host + h
            collector.Visit(url + "&page=1")
        })
    })

        // Retrieving totaleItems and pageOffset for calculate the max number of pages and then visiting
    collector.OnHTML(".query-to-page-navigator", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        totaleItems, pageOffset := extractMaxItemsAndOffsetFromPagination(e.Text)
        maxPages := int(math.Ceil(totaleItems / pageOffset))
        for i := 1; i <= int(maxPages); i++ {
            url := e.Request.URL.String()
            idxOf := strings.Index(url, "absolutepage")
            collector.Visit(fmt.Sprintf("%sabsolutepage=%d", url[:idxOf], i))
        }
    })

        // Navigate from the items list page to item detail page by looking the link
    collector.OnHTML(".query-to-list-container ul > li > a", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        link := e.Attr("href")
        collector.Visit(link)
    })

    // Finally in the detail page where I can get all the data I need
    collector.OnHTML(".my-data-container", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        // Doing stuff...
        aggregator = append(aggregator, e.ChildText(".my-beautiful-item"))
                // ...
    })

    collector.Visit(baseURL)
    collector.Wait()
    jsonFile := utils.PrepareJSON(aggregator)
    fileName := "test.json"
    _ = ioutil.WriteFile(fileName, jsonFile, 0644)
}

func extractMaxItemsAndOffsetFromPagination(paginator string) (float64, float64) {
    totaleItemsRegexp := regexp.MustCompile("<([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])>")
    pageOffsetRegexp := regexp.MustCompile("-([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]);")

    totaleItemsSub := totaleItemsRegexp.FindStringSubmatch(paginator)[1]
    pageOffsetSub := pageOffsetRegexp.FindStringSubmatch(paginator)[1]
    totaleItems, err := strconv.ParseFloat(totaleItemsSub, 32)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        totaleItems = -1
    }
    pageOffset, err := strconv.ParseFloat(pageOffsetSub, 32)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        pageOffset = -1
    }
    return totaleItems, pageOffset
}
```

I have read several topics and done various searches in the documentation, but so far I haven't found anything useful. I hope someone can help me better understand this part.

I have read several topics, videos, blog post and done various searches in the documentation, but so far I haven't found anything useful. In the past I tried to use a scraper in javascript and It worked perfectly. I expect to see the items returned from the call in the JSON file without any return errors from the call, but currently some items are missing, and many calls are failing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a working example of how to asynchronously scrape a website in a parallel way, you can refer to the following code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "github.com/gocolly/colly"
    "github.com/gocolly/colly/debug"
)

func main() {
    aggregator := []string{}

    c := colly.NewCollector(
        colly.Async(true),
        colly.Debugger(&debug.LogDebugger{}),
    )

    c.Limit(&colly.LimitRule{
        Parallelism: 4,
        RandomDelay: 2 * time.Second,
    })

    c.OnHTML("a[href]", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        link := e.Attr("href")
        aggregator = append(aggregator, link)
    })

    c.Visit("https://en.wikipedia.org/")
    c.Wait()
    if err := os.WriteFile("test.json", []byte(strings.Join(aggregator, "\n")), 0o644); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

I tested this code locally and it works as expected. No errors in the logs printed out onto the console. If you got an error with this code, this could be due to how you select the various elements on the page. Try to pay attention to this part. An option could be to start from scratch and incrementally add the complexity and refinements to get the desired nodes.
If that's not the case, let me know and I'll try to help you!

Comment: Hi, with my code example I can perform every call and after enabling colly.Debugger I'm sure that every call has been sent. I know what is happening in every part of the OnHTML and every part returns exactly what I expect but the logs showed me that many of the calls are failing. I'm starting to think that I'm performing too many async calls in a short period of time. This may cause a some sort of limitation or the activation of an anti-scraping policy by website I'm trying to call. It's just an hypotesis and I'm still trying to understand this part.

Comment: Keep me updated so! Another option could be to use `queue` which is a feature provided by `go-colly`. Some time ago, I faced a similar issue and it worked with this feature. Give it a try!